# Response Cache Attribute isn't override

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnetboilerplate version 5.13.0. I want response cache but it didn't work no matter what i tried. Response Header has always cache-control: no-cache, no-store.

I tried the following;

- I just added the response cache attribute.
- Response Cache middleware and cache profile.
- I defined DefaultResponseCacheAttributeForControllers in WebCoreModule PreInitialize

**Offical Documentation**;

```
    Abp provides a convenient way for you to configure the default Cache-Control header for all ApplicationService and Controller via IAbpAspNetCoreConfiguration
    
    DefaultResponseCacheAttributeForAppServices: Used if Controller class does not define Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ResponseCacheAttribute
    DefaultResponseCacheAttributeForControllers: Used if ApplicationService class does not define Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ResponseCacheAttribute
    Note: Cache-Control is not configured by default. You may configure for all ApplicationService and Controller then use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ResponseCacheAttribute at method/action level to override it.
```

But it is a bit difficult for me to understand. Does anyone have a code sample?